# Host React and Node.js on the same server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost

I have a hypothetical question about react and node. Let's say that I have a server where I want to host a react app and its backend application. That server has only port 3000 open to the public (anything open on port 3000 will be available through the URL). Could I run node.js (on let's say port 5000) and run react on port 3000, and make calls to the backend through the localhost:5000?

I'm not sure about this because the react code is hosted on the browser, so would it have access to the backend on that server?

Comment: This is a really general and open ended question, not well suited for SO. Why don't you try some sort of POC of what you are thinking and if you run into particular issues then come to stack overflow?

Comment: You can do this a few ways. You can host the UI code and API in the same server, depending on how you package assets. You can also forward API requests through your UI server to your back end. You could also do this via a proxy server on 3000 routing to servers for UI or API depending on path. This would all listen on a single public port.